# What are %I% and %G% identifiers in Object class javadoc?

Tags: java, eclipse, object

Just out of curiosity.

When I hover over `Object` word in eclipse, the doc shows the below info. I would like to know what the Version represent.

This does not appear on the online oracle javadocs
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

[image]

Also, futher checking `Object` class, the very intial comments show  `%W% %E%`. I would like to know what are these identifiers for?

Answer (score 2):

Those come from SCCS (Source Code Control System), the SCM Sun used to use. When a file was checked in %I% would be converted to the version of the file and %G% to the date the file was checked in. 
If memory serves correctly Sun moved to Mercurial around 2007 or so, so I don't think there's much danger of these getting updated!

%E% was the date (in yy/mm/dd format, where %G% was mm/dd/yy). I don't know about %W%!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Java Software used SCCS, which is an (old-fashioned!) source-code version control system, like git, Subversion or Perforce.

If you put "%I%, %G%" into a text file and then store that file in SCCS, when you check it back out, SCCS will expand the text to the file version and date. This is always present in Javadoc instructions such as in the [footnote of How to Write Doc Comment for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#footnote1)